# Is it possible to know the maximum value of density in advance?

Tags: r, probability-density, density-plot

Consider the following example plot:

```
mtcars %>% ggplot() + stat_bin(aes(x=wt, y=..density..), binwidth=0.2)
```

The maximum value of density is near to 0.8. Is it possible to know its **exact** value?

According to `stat_bin` documentation, `..density..` represents the *density of points in bin, scaled to integrate to 1*, but this does not help me to much to understand how these values are computed in practice, or how to get the maximum density point (as it also depends on the `binwidth` set).

The closer I have get is with:

```
binwidth = 0.2
((mtcars$wt %/% binwidth)*binwidth) %>% table %>% prop.table %>% max
```

But it does return the value observed in the plot.

Any ideas?

Comment: The docs also explain how the density curve is calculated, and how you can pass in parameters such as kernel and bandwidth. If you want control over those, you can set them explicitly

Comment: Rounding the values of the vector whose density is calculated is the closest I can think of the bins mentioned in the documentation. Alternatively, the command `cut` can also be used. In any case, the most probable (i.e. repeated) value in the vector won't match the higher bar returned by `stat_bin`, and this confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
binwidth=0.2
x=mtcars$wt
x_bins <- table(cut(x,breaks=seq(min(x),max(x),by = binwidth)),useNA = "ifany" )
max(x_bins)/(sum(x_bins)*binwidth )
#[1] 0.78125
```

or

```
gg_plot <- mtcars %>% ggplot() + stat_bin(aes(x=wt, y=..density..), binwidth=binwidth)
max(ggplot_build(gg_plot)$data[[1]][[1]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Not clear what *in advance* refers to but if you are looking for the maximum of the density curve then try this:

```
dens <- density(mtcars$wt)
plot(dens)

max(dens$y)
## [1] 0.5068726
```

Comment: By *in advance* I meant *before* computing `stat_bin` (or without computing it). This does answer the question, but it won't return the ~0.8 value given by the bars, how could I get it?